# How to check a two dimension file

Tags: java, file

So I am trying to create a connect 4 game.
The game is 2 dimensions of (6row)x(7col)
When I create a new game using a method to reset the frames,panels,labels for my GUI I create an empty file and I fill it with 0.
Example

```
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

While my game is playing and each player is making a move I want to go and find the exact location that was played and change the 0 to the players checker symbol where player1 is "1" and player 2 is "-1".
Example:

```
0  0  0  0  0  0  0 
0  0  0  0  0  0  0  
0  0  0  0  0  0  0
0  0  0  1  0  0  0 
0  0  0  1  0  0  0 
0  0  0  1 -1 -1 -1
```

After a different time period each time I want to make a button that saves these changes in order for me to be able to restart the game and reload the previous one into my GUI.

```
public static void file_write(int row,int col,int letter) throws IOException{
        int counter1 = 0; // a counter that goes +1 until reach the row 
        int counter2=0; // a counter that goes +1 until reach the col
        FileWriter writehandle;
        writehandle = new FileWriter("file.txt");
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(writehandle);
        FileReader readhandle = new FileReader("file.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(readhandle);

        if(Constants.once){ // boolean from class Constants that fills the file with 0. First example
        for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
            for(int j=0; j < 8; j++){
                Constants.line="0";
                bw.write(Constants.line + " "); // filling the file with 0
                }
        bw.newLine();
        }
    }
        if(letter == Constants.Player1) // player 1 symbol is 1
        for(int i=0; i<row;i++)
            for(int j=0; j<col; j++)

                if (br.readLine() == "0"  && counter2 != col){ //if statement in order to not change 
                    bw.write("0");                             //anything else except the player symbol i 
                    counter2++;                                //am looking for
                }
                else if(br.readLine() == " "   && counter2 != col){
                    bw.write(" ");
                    counter2++;
                }
                else if (br.readLine() == "-1" &&  counter2 != col){
                    bw.write("-1");
                    counter2++;
                }

                if(letter == Constants.Player1)
                bw.write("-1");
                else if (letter == Constants.Player2)
                    bw.write("1");
        bw.close();
        writehandle.close();
        Constants.once =false;
        file_read(0,0);


    }
```

So every time a move is taking place the code will get the row and col for it and call this method to make the appropriate change for the file.
My problem is I don't know how to move into the exact location to change the number using files and not arrays. The code doesn't seem to navigate into the location I want.
Help!

Answer (score 1):

Oh lord - rewriting in-place is gonna get very scary, and very error prone.

I realise this isn't strictly an answer to your question, but is there any reason you can't just load the whole file into memory, do the change, and write it back to disk again?

```
    static void write(Path outputFile, int[][] values) throws IOException {
        List<String> lines = Arrays.stream(values)
                .map(row -> Joiner.on("  ")
                        .join(Arrays.stream(row)
                                .mapToObj(Integer::toString)
                                .collect(Collectors.toList())))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
        Files.write(outputFile, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }

    static int[][] read(Path inputFile) throws IOException {
        int[][] result = new int[6][7];
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inputFile);
        Preconditions.checkState(lines.size() == 6);
        for (int lineIdx = 0; lineIdx < lines.size(); lineIdx ++) {
            String[] lineValues = lines.get(lineIdx).split("\\s\\s");
            Preconditions.checkState(lineValues.length == 7);
            for (int columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < lineValues.length; columnIndex++) {
                result[lineIdx][columnIndex] = Integer.parseInt(lineValues[columnIndex]);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```

And then, for example

```
static void examplePlayerOneMoves(int row, int col) {
    int[][] game = read(GAME_FILE);
    Preconditions.checkState(game[row, col] == 0);
    game[row][col] = 1;
    write(GAME_FILE, game);
}
```

The reason I'm reluctant to write the file in place is that manipulating streams like that byte-wise is very fragile, and is rarely a good idea if you want your code to be maintainable.

Comment: The requirement is to create a button responsible for saving the file and then another button to load it back to the GUI and continue playing from there. I am not sure if i overcomplicated things or not.

Comment: Sure -so you can just tie the “write” function to your save button, and the “read” function to your load button, right? Or am I missing something?

Comment: I will give it a try and let you know. Thanks though.